# `python -m pytest` vs pytest in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pytest

In my old virtual environment, I was able to execute `pytest tests/unit/` directly.

Then somehow I messed up my environment and had to remove and reinstall my `.venv`

Then after I activate the new `.venv` and reinstall all packages, I tried `pytest tests/unit/` but it gives this error:

```
(.venv) john@MacBook-Pro:~/myproject$ pytest tests/unit/nti/ -p no:warnings 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pytest: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

After some painful trials, I found that I can run tests with:

`(.venv) john@MacBook-Pro:~/myproject$ python -m pytest tests/unit/nti/ -p no:warnings`

SO, what is the difference between `python -m pytest` vs `pytest` ? Why would `pytest` fail to work but `python -m pytest` is fine?

Comment: `pytest` tries to run the module as the script itself, with the shebang (`!#...` line at the top) determining what interpreter to use. `python -mpytest` simply runs the module with `python`, ignoring the shebang. The problem would appear to be that `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6` no longer exists on your computer.

Comment: But how was it able to work in the old virtualenv in the first place... I followed the same steps setting up the old virtualenv as setting up the new.  Is there a way to make it work in the new virtualenv?

Comment: I find this confusing, too, as both `which python` and `which pytest` point to binaries inside the project venv folder. For `python -m pytest`, the `PATH` contains modules from the project directory, but just plain `pytest` fails because they're not on the `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

One possible option is that your 'tests' directory has no `__init__.py` inside it so you have to explicitly call the pytest module (`python -m pytest`).
To me this made the difference on Debian 10, Python 3.7.3 virtual environment and pytest 6.2.3.